# How to show divs inline. css html

Tags: html, css

I have many divs on page like this:

[image]

How i can dipslay this images inline to fill with

this is my source

```
<div id="ranks_content">
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/1" alt="Recruit" class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/2" alt="Apprentice " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/3" alt="Apprentice " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/4" alt="Private " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/5" alt="Private " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/6" alt="Copral " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/7" alt="Copral " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/8" alt="Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/9" alt="Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/10" alt="Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/11" alt="Gunnery Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/12" alt="Gunnery Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/13" alt="Gunnery Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/14" alt="Gunnery Sergeant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/15" alt="Lieutenant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/16" alt="Lieutenant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/17" alt="Lieutenant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/18" alt="Lieutenant " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/19" alt="Captain " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/20" alt="Captain " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/21" alt="Captain " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/22" alt="Captain " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/23" alt="Major " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/24" alt="Major " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/25" alt="Major " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/26" alt="Major " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/27" alt="Commander " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/28" alt="Commander " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/29" alt="Commander " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/30" alt="Commander " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/31" alt="Colonel " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/32" alt="Colonel " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/33" alt="Colonel " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/34" alt="Colonel " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/35" alt="Brigadier " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/36" alt="Brigadier " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/37" alt="Brigadier " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/38" alt="Brigadier " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/39" alt="General " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/40" alt="General " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/41" alt="General " class="rank_picture"/>
    <img src="/Ranks/GetRankImage/42" alt="General " class="rank_picture"/>
</div>
```

Edit: Im using CSS3 and this is example how i want to display this images

[image]

Comment: What CSS are you using?  Can you  please explain what you're looking to do a little more?

Comment: With the HTML you're showing us, the images would display like that - see this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7WrUn/  There must be some CSS in play here or you would already be getting the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your second image, I've made a Fiddle Example to better illustrate how to achieve your end goal:

See the [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/wVs8U/)

**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
<div id="ranks_content" class="clearfix">
  ...
  <div>
    <span>Commander</span>
    <img alt="" src="path_to_image.png" width="64" height="64">
    <span>5.0</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS TO MAKE IT HAPPEN**

```
/* not needed, used just for the demo */
body {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
#ranks_content {
  margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFF;
}

/* the necessary HTML starts here */
#ranks_content > div {
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
#ranks_content > div > span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#ranks_content > div > img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* helpers */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after  {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

[image]

**Notes:**

Since you are requesting some help about how to positioning the images, but your second image shows that you are going to use some text, the best approach would be to wrap every image and related text inside a `div`. Floating the `div` to the left will allow the images to stay side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

will this be fine ?

just set the img width :

http://jsfiddle.net/7WrUn/2/

```
.rank_picture
{
    width:100px;
}​
```

### edit

see the enhance ver :http://jsfiddle.net/7WrUn/2/

[image]

p.s. : 
ive been adding some jQuery in order for you to see the final result .

i thing you display the alt as a title. but in my fiddle - you see it twice - since i dont have any images.

if you have , youll see them once + value.

Comment: Unless some other CSS has set images to display block, they are already inline by default.  I don't mean to criticize your answer - the question is incomplete.  Not your fault.